# Error Message: No JIRA site configured | Using JiraCloud

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have setup Jira & Jenkins Integration. I'm using the typical Jira Cloud `<orgname>.atlassian.net`. So far `jiraSendBuildInfo`, `jiraSendDeploymentInfo` are working.

However when I tried using `jiraTransitionIssue` I received error `No JIRA site configured with <org>.atlassian.net` name.

I tried adding Jira Site in Jira Steps configuration, however I was unable to select credentials. I added atlassian API token in the credentials but for some reason it's not showing on the list.

PS: I'm using JIRA API Token because atlassian Username & Password is now deprecated.

`JIRA STEPS Plugin Version: 1.6.0`

[image]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

email as a username & API Token from `https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens` as a password works.